# How to send the returned boolean result from controller to view in spring mvc

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I want to send the controller method returned value( i.e flag) to my view and in view i need to display an alert message according to this flag.This is my controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testing", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Boolean testing(@RequestBody String value, HttpSession session, String username, ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
  Boolean flag = false;
  User userData = (User) session.getAttribute("MEMBER");
  for (OrgData org: orgDataRepository.findAll()) {
    if (m.getValue() != null) {
      sourceAccessToken = (String) m.getValue();
      flag = true;
    } else {
      System.out.println("Refresh token is expired");
      flag = false;
    }
  }
  return flag;
}
```

My view code looks something like below

```js
let btnVal = document.querySelectorAll('.test-btn');
for (let i = 0; i < btnVal.length; i++) {
  let btns = btnVal[i];
  btns.onclick = function() {
    var selchbox = getSelectedChbox(this.form); // gets the array returned by getSelectedChbox()
    if (selchbox.length == 1) {
      //document.write("check check"+selchbox);
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/testing",
        dataType: "JSON",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(selchbox),
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
          alert("SUCCESS!!!");
        },
        error: function(args) {
          /* alert("Error on ajax post");
          console.log("Error"+args); */
        }

      });
    } else {
      alert("Please select only one check box");
    }

  }
}
```

I want to send that boolean value in this ajax call and display a popup window or alert box. How to achieve this?

Comment: What is your problem, specifically? Is there an error?

Comment: I want to send the flag to my view and display an alert message.How to do that?

Comment: I understand what you want, you said it three times now: two times in question body, once in comments. You still didn't say why your code doesn't work.

Comment: I really didn't call the flag in view.I am not sure how to do that. I need help in calling the returned value in the view

Comment: Try inspecting arguments that get passed to `success` callback.

Comment: I see you've never accepted any answers on any questions you've asked.  You might want to start trying that.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try such code in success function:

```
 success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            alert("Success!");
        } else {
            alert("False value.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be doing anything with your server value.
You need to return it to the client.
Since you are using spring, you should be able to return json to your ajax call.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/testing", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Map testAjax() {
  return Collections.singletonMap("flag", true);
}
```

Then your ajax call can retrieve the value:

```
        success: function (data) {
        console.log("Success");
             console.log(data);
             alert(data.flag)
      },
      error: function (args) {
          console.log("error");
          console.log(args);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the property `dataType: "JSON"` from your ajax call. B'coz what you are returning is a simple boolean value. But the property indicates that the response it is expecting is a JSON which is not true in this case. And then use the code like

```
success: function (data) {
      if (data) {
          // your true code here
      } else {
         // your false code here
      }
 }
```